# Difficulties locating specific button within a modal dialog - Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, modal-dialog

I'm having a spot of bother trying to click on a button within a modal dialog.  I searched the web but seems either I'm getting myself confused(likely) or the solutions on other arent working in my specific case.

The use case is as follows:

1. In the default content page I click on an icon to insert an image into a text editor.
2. A modal dialog pops up and I click an upload button
3. the windows file navigator opens and i paste the file path into the 'File name' textinputbox and confirm the submission.  The windows file navigatr then closes
4. The modal dialog updates with the uploaded file name and I click 'Add' button
5. A new window pops up and I confirm some further details by checking a checkbox and clicking an ok button
6. The popup window disappears and the modaldialog from step 2 and 4 either disappears or changes into a new modal dialog warning me that there are duplicate files and whether to 'update' or 'cancel'.  I want to press this update button.

I'm tripping up on this last final step.  I just cant locate this button.  Perhaps it has just been a long day and I am now too tired.  So so help would be appreciated before I start headbanging the desk.

The html is as follows:

```
<div class="d2l-dialog" style="top: 318px; width: 400px; height: 420px; left: 680px; z-index: 1008;">
<div class="d2l-dialog-inner" style="height: 418px;">
<iframe class="d2l-dialog-frame" src="/d2l/lp/fileinput/6606/Duplicates?files=photo.jpg" name="d2l_c_1_783" allowfullscreen="" scrolling="no" style="width: 398px; height: 418px; overflow: hidden;" frameborder="0">
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-lang-default="en-GB" lang="en-GB">
<head>
<body class="d2l-body d2l-typography vui-typography d2l-dialog-document-body" style="overflow: hidden;">
<div id="MathJax_Message" style="display: none;"></div>
<div class="d2l-dialog-width d2l_1_0_132 d2l-dialog-flex" data-height="420" style="width: 398px;">
<div class="d2l-dialog-title d2l-dragdrop-draggable">
<div class="d2l-dialog-body" style="height: 336px;">
<div class="d2l-dialog-footer-container">
<div class="d2l-dialog-footer">
<div class="d2l-dialog-buttons">
<div class="d2l-dialog-button-group">
<a id="d2l_1_2_435" class="vui-button d2l-button vui-button-primary" role="button" tabindex="0" aria-disabled="false">Update</a>
<a id="d2l_1_3_576" class="vui-button d2l-button" role="button" tabindex="0" aria-disabled="false">Cancel</a>
<span tabindex="0"></span>
</div>
<div class="d2l-clear"></div>
</div>
<span class="d2l-dialog-resize"></span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://s.brightspace.com/lib/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://s.brightspace.com/lib/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://s.brightspace.com/lib/bsi/10.6.2-4/bsi.min.js">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/d2l/common/assets/tock/tock.min.js?v=10.6.7.4465-92">
```

This is one of my attempts:

```
Thread.sleep(1000);
driver.switchTo().activeElement();
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[contains(@name, 'd2l_c_1_')]")));
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[starts-with(@id,'d2l_1_2_']")).click();
```

It times out on the line:

```
driver.switchTo().activeElement();
```

I tried removing this but it doesn't work.  Some assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my issue it was a stupid error that I made.  In step 5 above I forgot to change back to the original window and then search for the iframe the code itself was mostly fine after some modification.

```
npc.get_window_ids();
driver.switchTo().window(npc.getWindow2());
driver.manage().window().maximize();

//click add  
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='checkbox']")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='d2l_form']/div[2]/div[1]/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[1]/a")).click();

Thread.sleep(1000);
//forgot to add this line DOH!
driver.switchTo().window(npc.getWindow1());
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[contains(@name, 'd2l_c_1_')]")));
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[starts-with(@id,'d2l_1_2_')]")).click();
```